# Converting XHTML to XAML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I have the following XML

```
User entered text : Normal **Bold** *Italic* 
u&#x332;n&#x332;d&#x332;e&#x332;r&#x332;l&#x332;i&#x332;n&#x332;e&#x332;
***BoldItalic*** ***B&#x332;o&#x332;l&#x332;d&#x332;I&#x332;t&#x332;a&#x332;l&#x332;i&#x332;c&#x332;U&#x332;n&#x332;d&#x332;e&#x332;r&#x332;l&#x332;i&#x332;n&#x332;e&#x332;***
```

The resulting XHTML string is stored in the database table.

```
  <QuestionText xml:space="preserve">
    <p>Normal 
    <b>Bold </b> 
    <i>Italic </i>
    <u>Underline </u>

    <b>Bold <i>BoldItalic </i>Bold </b> 

    <b><i>BoldItalic </i></b> 
    <b><i><u>BoldItalicUnderline</u></i></b> 
    </p>
    <p/>
    <p/>
    <p/>
  </QuestionText>
```

I need to transform to .Net X(A)ML as follows

```
<Section>
  <Paragraph>
    <Span Text="Nornal " />
    <Span FontWeight="Bold" Text="Bold " />
    <Span FontStyle="Italic" Text="Italic " />
    <Span Text="Underline " UnderlineDecoration="Line" />

    <Span FontWeight="Bold" Text="Bold " />
    <Span FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold" Text="BoldItalic " />
    <Span FontWeight="Bold" Text="Bold " />

    <Span FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold" Text="BoldItalic " />
    <Span FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold" Text="BoldItalicUnderline" UnderlineDecoration="Line" />
  </Paragraph>
  <Paragraph/>
  <Paragraph/>
  <Paragraph/>
</Section>
```

I tried with this XSLT with no luck

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="QuestionText">
      <Section>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </Section>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="b|i|u|p/text()" >

    <span>
      <xsl:attribute name="Text">
        <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="parent">
        <xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/>
      </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:if test=".=i">
        <xsl:attribute name="FontStyle">italic</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:if test=".=b">
        <xsl:attribute name="FontWeight">bold</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:if test=".=u">
        <xsl:attribute name="UnderlineDecoration">line</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
    </span>

    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <Paragraph>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Paragraph>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help on XSLT is highly appreciated.

Comment: The data you show as you source XML isn't valid XML. I have applied markdown for your question so that it shows the text literally, but I am not at all certain what you are asking.

Comment: Note to all: `&#x332;` is the Unicode combining underline character.

Comment: No luck......in what sense?

Comment: @JLRishe, With the new XML, the XSLT is not transforming as expected. Can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This essentially produces the sample output you provided:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="QuestionText">
    <Section>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </Section>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space()]" >
    <Span Text="{.}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*" mode="formatting" />
    </Span>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="i" mode="formatting">
    <xsl:attribute name="FontStyle">italic</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="b" mode="formatting">
    <xsl:attribute name="FontWeight">bold</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="u" mode="formatting">
    <xsl:attribute name="UnderlineDecoration">line</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*" mode="formatting" />

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <Paragraph>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </Paragraph>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<Section>
  <Paragraph>
    <Span Text="Normal &#xA;    " />
    <Span Text="Bold " FontWeight="bold" />
    <Span Text="Italic " FontStyle="italic" />
    <Span Text="Underline " UnderlineDecoration="line" />

    <Span Text="Bold " FontWeight="bold" />
    <Span Text="BoldItalic " FontWeight="bold" FontStyle="italic" />
    <Span Text="Bold " FontWeight="bold" />

    <Span Text="BoldItalic " FontWeight="bold" FontStyle="italic" />
    <Span Text="BoldItalicUnderline" FontWeight="bold" FontStyle="italic" UnderlineDecoration="line" />
  </Paragraph>
  <Paragraph />
  <Paragraph />
  <Paragraph />
</Section>
```

The issue is the `&#xA;` in that first Span, because the first text node in the source XML includes a newline and whitespace after it. How would you like to address that? It would be easy to put a `normalize-space()` in the `Text` attribute, but that would also strip out other trailing spaces as well.

Comment: You saved my day. You are the Hero.

Comment: I have one issue. If the xml content has : <b>Bold <i>BoldItalic </i></b>, then I am not getting the desired result. <Span Text="Bold " FontWeight="bold" /> <Span Text="BoldItalic " FontStyle="italic" FontWeight="bold" />. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @teenboy Modified my answer to suit your new requirements. If you need to your requirements after the fact, please consider opening a new question instead of rescinding an Accept on an answer that already fit your originally stated requirements.

Comment: I thought, it will (nearly) duplicate the question. So I edited the question. Next time on-wards, I will create new question. Once again many thanks.